# MailMan moderator subscribe via email

Tags: mailman

I am setting up a MailMan list server and I am trying to find a way for moderators to subscribe users through email. We are only using the MailMan website for the administrators and need the moderators to be able to at least subscribe people and/or accept subscription requests from users. Is there anyway to do this and besides turning off require approval? Thanks.

Comment: Another way that this could work is if I can set it where only moderators can use the subscribe command and then I can just set the privacy options to wide open and not require approval since I know only the moderators are doing the commands. Is this possible?

Comment: Why can't the moderators just use the web interface to manage subscriptions?

Comment: Maye best place to ask is the Mailman mailing list: mailman-users@python.org

Answer (score 1):

Mailman's email interface does not support what you want to do.

You must use the web interface to manage subscriptions. It's very easy to use.